# How to get selected date from highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock to show time based values. I need to get the date range shown in the chart for other purposes. Is there some easy way to get the begin-end values?

Answer (score 8):

Use [getExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.getExtremes())

```
var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes(),
     start = new Date(extremes.min),
     end   = new Date(extremes.max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.axes[0].dataMax
chart.axes[0].dataMin
```